# Ajax success return value use in other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On file upload, I want ajax hit the url like:

```
$.ajax(
    { url: '<?php echo base_url();?>apk-reader/ApkInfo.php',
      data: {"apps": "../apps/apk_files/"+file, user_id: "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>"},
      type: 'get',
      success: function(output) { alert(output);}
```

Here I want to store the out put in another variable and use it in OnComplete of another ajax load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'your URL',
      data: {"your Parameter"},
       type: 'get',
      success: function(data) { 
           AjaxMethode(data)
       }
  });

function AjaxMethode(data){
    if(data.d){
        //someCode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call other function from success and pass the result to it, SomeFunction(output);

```
$.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url();?>apk-reader/ApkInfo.php',
      data: {"apps": "../apps/apk_files/"+file, user_id: "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>"},
       type: 'get',
      success: function(output) { 
           alert(output);SomeFunction(output)
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable in global scope and store your output in that varibale. Now you can access the global variable at the callback of any other ajax method,

```
var result1;
$.ajax( { url: 'apk-reader/ApkInfo.php', data: {"apps": "../apps/apk_files/"+file, user_id: "session->userdata('user_id'); ?>"}, type: 'get', success: function(output) { alert(output);
result1=output;
}
$.ajax( { url: 'apk-reader2/ApkInfo.php', data: {"apps": "../apps/apk_files/"+file, user_id: "session->userdata('user_id'); ?>"}, type: 'get', success: function(output2) { alert(output2);
alert(result1);
```

}

Comment: I would say avoid global variables unless they're necessary. If one function is dependent on the results of another, just pass the results. There's no need to store it globally and access it.

Comment: @Yatrix yeah! i agree with you